# If $X \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, is it true that $\mathbb P(X \geq a)>0$ for all $a>0$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

If $X \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, is it true that $\mathbb P(X \geq a)>0$ for all $a>0$?

I guess the answer is yes since I think we have
$\mathbb P(X \geq a)=\int_a^{\infty} f(x)dx > 0,$
where $f$ is the density function of the random variable $X$.

Comment: You're correct. [In fact](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/norm-dist-bounds), $\Bbb P(X\ge a)\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{a}{a^2+1}e^{-a^2/2}$.

Comment: It is in fact true for all real $a$, positive negative or $0$.  All normal distributions have support on the whole real number line

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true, since for the normally distributed random variable there is no upper limit on the values it can generate.